# iPhone SDK Noob Problem with Search Bar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I hope you will reply to this:

I once had this kind of array:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object1", @"Object2", @"Object3", nil];
NSDictionary *arrayDictionaryDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"Key"];

[listOfItems addObject:arrayDictionaryDict];
```

Now I have this:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object1", @"Subtitle1", @"Object2", @"Subtitle2", @"Object3", @"Subtitle3", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"title", @"subtitle", @"title", @"subtitle", @"title", @"subtitle", nil]];

listOfItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dictA, nil];
```

I also had a search bar with this method:

```
// in search the table view void
[…]
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems) {

     NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Key"];
 [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

}
```

[B]How should I change this last method to fit the new Array and search both in the title and subtitle?[/B]

Thanx

Comment: Just a short side note: An NSDictionary can't hold objects that share the same key. You can have one object for the key @"title" and one for the key @"subtitle", but not three.

Comment: I see. Then, how should I do to make the Table View to be sectioned using both searchable title and subtitle per cell?

Comment: You could create an NSArray that holds NSDictionary each one with a @"title" and @"subtitle" key

Comment: What do you mean? I can't imagine it. Could you make an example, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary allValues];
```

This returns an NSArray with all saved values. If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are looking for.